# Variable in NASM

Tags: c, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to convert those lines:

```
struct node * head;
struct node * tail;
```

into nasm (x86-64). The code is partially in C and partially in assembly.

Should I write in `section .bss` something like this:

```
head resb 8
tail resb 8
```

also making it global in `section .text`:

```
global head:data 8
global tail:data 8
```

? It doesn't want to work :/ I know that the pointer is in fact an address, so something like `unsigned long`.

=====

Here is the the struct:

```
struct node
{
    unsigned long length;
    char * buf;
    struct node * previous;
    struct node * next;
};
```

Comment: Use `global` for variables you are *defining* in your assembly file. Use `extern` for external variables that you are using that are defined in another module or library. You don't want `resb` declarations because that *defines* the variables, and the assembly file isn't defining them, but using them. Just use `extern head, tail`.

Comment: My final goal is to convert the entire code in C to assembly. Thus in the end it will be defined in the assembly file :) Sorry for not stating this.

Comment: Your declarations say `extern` in your question and you asked how to convert those. Even if the entire set of code is written in assembly, if you are trying to reference those variables from one assembly module when they're defined in another, you need `extern`. And then in the file they're defined, you'd use `global` and the `resb` declarations are fine in the defining module.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Working with structures in NASM](http://mcs.uwsuper.edu/sb/224/Intro/struct_nasm.html).

Comment: I just want to define a pointer to struct in the assembly file, not going into working with structures yet. I mean I want to write in assembly file `struct node * head;`, but in C file write `extern struct node * head;`. The pointer will be defined in the assembly file.

Comment: OK, I thought you said you were ultimately rewriting all of your code in assembly. If you're referencing an external structure, you might still want to look at that link for a handy way to define structure offsets. Or use equates to define them to make the code readable.

Comment: @Randolph, I think the point that is a bit muddy for you is that in `x86_64` assembly, all pointers are `8-bit`, so any variable you define as `db` can be a pointer to your `struct`. The crux of assembly is simply handling what is in memory. Your `pointer to struct` in `nasm` will simply be an `8-bit` variable holding the beginning address to your struct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am still fighting with it and it throws segmentation fault :( I have my code in C, where I am using head and tail. But I want to **define** head and tail in my assembly file. I wrote there (in assebly) head resb 8 in .bss and global head:data 8 in .text. As in the post. It doesn't want to work :/

Comment: You can reserve space in `.bss` or you can simply declare a block in `.data` the size you need to hold `head` and `tail`. The `times` directive can be used to specify any number of sequential bytes. So if you want `8` bytes, you could use `head times 8 db 0` to create `head` pointing to `8-bytes` of zero'ed memory in `.data`. You can then mov your address to `head` overwriting the zeros even though the information in `.data` is 'constant'.  This can often be convenient. To see exactly what you are trying to do, can you edit and post what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define your global variables in data section so you can initialize the values. Pointers can be defined simply as quad words using `dq`:

```
section .data

global head
head dq 0

global tail
tail dq 0
```